# order of evaluating recursive tree path with promises

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

This code is claimed to procced first with directories and after that with subdirectories  recursively.But the order wouldnt be directoryA directoryA/subdirectoryC directory B .A and B are children of root dir

```
 const {join} = require('path');
 const {promisify} = require('util');
 const fs = require('fs');
 const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir);
 const stat = promisify(fs.stat);
 async function $readDir (dir, acc = []) {
 await Promise.all((await readdir(dir)).map(async file => {
      file = join(dir, file);
      return (await stat(file)).isDirectory() && acc.push(file) && 
      $readDir(file, acc);
      }));
 return acc;
 }
```

The order seems to be root:/dirA root:/dirb root:/dirA/dirC
in the tree of promises the inner ones get fullfillment first
and the final order is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm you are looking for is called BFS or "breadth first search". It applies to not just directories but general [graph traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Not that this is generally not a recursive algorithm.

The idea is to visit each level in a turn and push everything you find from the next level in a queue and then process that queue:

```
const { join } = require('path');
const fs = require('fs').promises;
async function readdirRecursive (dir, acc = []) {
  var queue = [dir];
  while(queue.length > 0) {
    var next = queue.shift();
    // this code does this sequentially and not concurrently
    // if you want to make multiple fs calls then you can by storing
    // levels and doing the call once - per - level, but you already had
    // that

    if (!(await fs.stat(file)).isDirectory()) {
      return; // file, return
    }

    // put code that does something with dir here

    const files = await fs.readdir(next);
    // add all the new candidates
    queue.push(...files.map(f => path.join(next, f)); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP actually wants a depth first traversal, it's just that his current results are different.

Comment: Why? He said "This code is claimed to procced first with directories and after that with subdirectories recursively." and the code doesn't do that but the code I wrote does since BFS uses a queue.

Comment: OK, I didn't really understand what or who claimed anything about the code, just that `directoryA - directoryA/subdirectoryC - directoryB` seemed to be the expected output.

Comment: Well, from a graph point of view it indicates that the traversal is in depth rather than in breadth since an async call finishes before some other async call and the order isn't guaranteed - which is why I posted code that gurantees order.

Answer (score 0):

All the function calls that are mapping over your array of subdirectories run concurrently, and if you just push to your accumulator array there is no guaranteed order at all.

To fix that, either traverse the directories sequentially:

```
async function readDirRecursive(dir, acc = []) {
    for (const file of await readdir(dir)) {
        const path = join(dir, file);
        if ((await stat(path)).isDirectory()) {
            acc.push(path);
            await readDirRecursive(path, acc);
        }
    }
    return acc;
}
```

or just don't use a shared accumulator but properly concatenate the result of the concurrent traversals in the order that you want:

```
async function readDirRecursive(dir) {
    const paths = await Promise.all((await readdir(dir)).map(async file => {
        const path = join(dir, file);
        if ((await stat(path)).isDirectory())
            return [path, ...await readDirRecursive(path, acc)];
        else
            return [];
    });
    return [].concat(...paths);
}
```

Comment: well althought this can be considered solved by de bsf algorithm,in the qwestion order as seens by many (is async) isnt guarrateed but INDEED always that is executed under debian ,it keeps the bsf order with adding nothing more than the firts post. It seems the message loop keeps things going this way(the msg loop of node.js) AND await plus promises keep them until each level is fullfilled